# In "Status report" it just outputs the string "version", which causes problems when querying Drupal version

Tags: webforms

When I go to "**Status report**" menu, only the string "**version**" is getting printed, which can cause problems with some modules like Webform.
I have Drupal **6.22**, but in the "Status report", Webform writes *"Webform requires at least version 6.16 of Drupal core."*, which means the problem above can be a possible reason.
How can I fix that?

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Drupal Status Report - writing the string 'version']

[image: Drupal Status Report - 'Webform requires at least version 6.16 of Drupal core.']

---

EDIT

The file `system.module` contains

```
define('VERSION', '6.22');
```

on line 11, which is correct, BUT the return value of this function was `bool(false)` (after checking it with a `var_dump()`), which [means](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) a failure (like when this was defined earlier or sg similar). After that, I put the following line **BEFORE** the above mentioned define function:

```
var_dump(defined('VERSION'));die();
```

and it gave back `bool(true)`, which means this constant has already been defined!
I still don't know where, why and how...

There's a function with the name `_drupal_bootstrap_full()` (in /includes/common.inc, line 2673), in which `module_load_all()` function is called. The "`VERSION`" constant is defined after calling this function (and its value is "version" then), but knowing that doesn't make an advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my own question, after a long investigation.

**It's a "bug" (or a programming idiocy)** in the **[JW Player Module](http://drupal.org/project/jwplayermodule)**!!!

**As soon as I [disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjki9.png) it, I went to "Status report", and everything was OK!!**

Here is the proof, look at this (since asking my question, I modified the admin theme):

[image: JW Player Module disabled: everything's OK with Drupal version number]

BUT as soon as I reenable JW Player Module, version number is wrong again!
Here's a screenshot after reenabling the module again:

[image: JW Player Module enabled: Drupal version wrong again!!]

I think I should report this bug...
Hope this helped someone who uses JW Player Module.
I try to find the code in the module where this problem occurs, I will tell if I found it.

---

EDITING:

Since then I can see that this bug is already reported on Drupal's official site!
Here's the bug report: ["Constant VERSION already defined"](http://drupal.org/node/1234562).

The source of the problem is in the 18th line of the file `/modules/jwplayermodule/jwplayermodule.module`:

```
define("VERSION", "version");
```

I don't really understand why there was a need to do that, but the programmer who put this line into this file deserves a kickass! :) It cost me a couple of hours.... and it absolutely doesn't make sense that it's in the code - for example, a JW_PLAYER_VERSION constant could be used, or any other constants that is NOT in Drupal core...

Answer (score 2):

That is weird. What does line 11 of the file `modules/system/system.module` read? For me, it is `define('VERSION', '6.22')`. How did you obtain the Drupal source files? Via a zipfile or through a git check out perhaps?

Comment: thank you for your answer, line 11 contains the same line as in your file: define('VERSION', '6.22');, which is correct (I'll edit my original post and put this info into it). But I simply don't understand how it gets overridden later: there are two lines in index.php: require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); ---> When I put the line echo VERSION;die(); after it, it also echoes the "version" string... Really weird. I got Drupal from the original source: http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-6.22.zip . Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I put a code in the system.module file before the mentioned 11th line: var_dump(defined('VERSION'));die();, and it gives back bool(true), which means it's already defined before!! How could this happen? :D For for the time being I don't know where (in which file) to start investigating...

Comment: OK, since then I found the "solution": disabling JW Player Module... I found it a bit strange that a module can cause problems like this. Please look at my answer to the question. Could you also try this module on your system? I'm curious to know if it's my own problem or it's general. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I can only reproduce that behavior by changing `modules/system/system.module` like so

```
define('VERSION', 'version');
```

When I remove the line altogether the Status report page contains string `VERSION` in uppercase...

You may want to have a look in your `modules/system/system.module` ;-)

Comment: I edited my original post: my system.module file is correct, BUT the VERSION constant already exists before including system.module file... I don't know how and where. "When I remove the line altogether the Status report page contains string VERSION in uppercase..." --> I think the reason for that is that if you remove the whole line, and VERSION constant is not defined, PHP assumes this is a string: you would get a PHP notice like this: "Notice: Use of undefined constant VERSION - assumed 'VERSION'", but it's hidden because of your settings.

Comment: That's right. I was rather referring to the fact, that even if you had the whole line missing from system.module, the version string still wouldn't show up in lowercase like you have it in the screenshots. It looks like it is explicitly defined to version somewhere. You can try to grep the code for "version" and 'version'.

Comment: Since then I found the answer, please look at it: JW Player Module is buggy! As soon as I disabled it, everything was alright, look at the screenshots... I couldn't find the source of the problem in JW Player Module's code, but I'm trying to... but could you please also try this module if this problem occurs on your system too? Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: OK, found the source of the problem in the code, please look at it. You got a +1 too. :)